# Can't regain administrator privileges after hiding the admin's account on win log-on

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts, administrator, regedit

I've followed the guide [here](http://www.download3k.com/articles/How-to-hide-or-unhide-user-accounts-from-the-Windows-8.1-login-screen-01096) to hide the admin's account from log on area but now i only have a standard account left and i can't access `regedit` as admin to do the necessary work and bring the admin account back. when i want to access the `regedit` as admin, it doesn't even show admin's account as if the admin's account not only is hidden from log on but it's also hidden from every part of the Windows. i'm using Windows 8.1. Please help i need to know how can i get admin's account back.

Comment: Did you hide it as admin? Are you trying to unhide it from non-admin?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened..

Comment: Use the tool of your choice that can create an Administrator user outside of Windows.